# How do I set the WCF error message return format in code?

Tags: wcf

I have a service contract like this:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "getdata?key={key}&format={format}")]
Event[] GetIncidentsXml(string key, string format);
```

In code, I'm switching out the response format like this:

```
var selectedFormat = ParseWebMessageFormat(format);
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = selectedFormat;
```

*(ParseWebMessageFormat being a method to wrap up Enum parsing for the type)*

This part works as expected and I get either XML or JSON depending on the passed parameter.

Where it falls down is when I throw an exception. If the (API) key that's passed in is invalid, I'm doing this:

```
var exception = new ServiceResponse
{
    State = "fail", 
    ErrorCode = new ErrorDetail { Code = "100", Msg = "Invalid Key" }
};

throw new WebProtocolException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid Key.", exception, null);
```

When an exception is thrown, the return type is *always* XML:

```
<ServiceResponse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IBI.ATIS.Web.ServiceExceptions" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ErrorCode>
        <Code>100</Code>
        <Msg>Invalid Key</Msg>
    </ErrorCode>
    <State>fail</State>
</ServiceResponse>
```

The return type change is the first line of code in the the service method so is happening before the exception is thrown.

I know I can set WCF to return type based on the request format, but it's a requirement to use the type passed in through the query string.

Automatic message type is switched off in config:

```
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you will need to specify the default response format somehow. The behavior you are seeing is standard. You will need to to look and specific headers and determine what the response format should be. You can then implement a request interceptor to figure out what the outgoing response format needs to be.

So to answer your question, you will need to stick with a default format type if none is mentioned or return a bad request. REST is more of a paradigm than a protocol unlike SOAP.

UPDATE: For clarification sake. You could do something like this.

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface ICustomerService
{
   [OperationContract]
   [WebGet(UriTemplate ="?format={formatType}",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
   IResponseMessage GetEmCustomers(string formatType);

}

public class CustomerService : ServiceBase
{
  IResponseMessage GetEmCustomers(string formatType)
  {
    try
    {
      var isValid  = base.validateformatspecification(formatType);// check to see if format is valid and supported
      if(!isValid) return base.RespondWithError(formatType,new Error {Msg= "Dude we dont support this format"});
      var customers = CustomerProvider.GetAll();
      return base.Respond(formatType,customer);// This method will format the customers in desired format,set correct status codes and respond.
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
      // log stuff and do whatever you want
      return base.RespondWithError(formatType,new Error{Msg = "Aaah man! Sorry something blew up"});// This method will format the customers in desired format,set correct status codes and respond.

    }      
  }    
}

public class ServiceBase
{
  public IResponseMessage Respond<T>(string format,T entity);
  public IResponseMessage RespondWithError<T>(string format, T errorObject);

}

public class Error:IResponseMessage {/*Implementation*/}

public class GetEmCustomerResponseResource:List<Customer>,IResponseMessage {/* Implementation*/}

public class GetEmCustomerErrorResponse: IResponseMessage {/* Implementation   */}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. The format type is a parameter to the method. Successful calls are correctly returned as the type specified in the call. It's only the error message that isn't sent in the specified output format. What would I need to look for in the request headers?

Comment: So WCF ignores set output types when it throws an error. That's annoying. I was hoping it'd be a simple config change or something I'd overlooked. Thanks for your help.